# get all the child terms from a parent term

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to get all the child terms from a parent term from my termset.

```
$Group = $termStore.Groups["grp1F"]
write-host Connection made with group - $Group.Name
$termset = $Group.termsets["ts1"]

foreach ($singleterm in $termset)
{
    if ($term.Name -eq "trm1") { }
}

$ggterm = $termset.GetTerms("GG",$true)

Write-Host  "current parent term name is" $ggterm.Name
```

`

But would like to know how to get the childterms under GG. in my termstore, i have some 20+ childterms under gg. How to retrieve this.
help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

[Term.GetTerms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.term.getterms.aspx) method will return all the terms under a given term. Here is the sample code from your example:

```
$ggterm = $termset.GetTerms("GG",$true)
foreach ($term in $ggterm)
{
    $childTerms = $term.GetTerms();
    foreach ($cterm in $childTerms)
    {
        Write-Host  $cterm.Name
    }
}
```